# Django URL and Views

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-1.9, django-1.10

Since this below method of Mapping Django Url from a view is depreciated in Django 1.9 and above

> url(r'^contact/$', 'newsletter.views.contact', name='contact'),
>
> url(r'^about/$', 'home.views.about', name='about'),

And this is what is currently in place

> from newsletter import views'
>
> url(r'^about/$', 'views.about', name='about'),

How do i Map my url for 2 different app views

> from home import views
>
> from newsletter import views
>
> url(r'^home/$', 'views.home', name='home'), #located in home
>
> url(r'^about/$', 'views.about', name='about'), #located in newsletter

Mapping like i did above will result to an error so i need help. New to Django

Comment: try from home import views as home_views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by using a fully qualified module name being deprecated since it is a core python construct. 
But you can manage two different modules containing submodules with the same name by binding them to different aliases using the "import as" statement.

Example:

```
from home import views as home_view
from newsletter import views as news_view
```

Then you can use the aliases `home_view` and `news_view` to reference each module instead of `views`, throughout the declared namespace.

You can take a look at the import statement syntax in the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> If the requested module is retrieved successfully, it will be made
>   available in the local namespace in one of three ways:
>
> - If the module name is followed by as, then the name following as is
>     bound directly to the imported module.
> - If no other name is specified,
>     and the module being imported is a top level module, the module’s name
>     is bound in the local namespace as a reference to the imported module
> - If the module being imported is not a top level module, then the name
>     of the top level package that contains the module is bound in the
>     local namespace as a reference to the top level package. The imported
>     module must be accessed using its full qualified name rather than
>     directly

Comment: The question is about passing a string that is later resolved by Django. In newer versions Django expects a function object and won't resolve a string with the full path to the function object.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from home import views as home_views

from newsletter import views

url(r'^home/$', 'home_views.home', name='home'), #located in home

url(r'^about/$', 'views.about', name='about'), #located in newsletter
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can only import the view functions:

```
from home.views import home
from newsletter.views import about

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', about, name='about'),
]
```